# how to insert multiple images to database in one row

Tags: php, html, mysqli

**I have made up this html form**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image1" /><br/>
  <input type="file" name="image2" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" name='submit' value="upload" />
</form>
```

**this is my php code**

```
<?php
 include "conf/connect.php";

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

                $uploadpath1 = 'upload/';

                $image1_name = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
                $image1_size = $_FILES['image1']['size'];
                $image1_type = $_FILES['image1']['type'];
                $image1_url =
                $image1_temp_name = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];

                $uploadpath1 = $uploadpath1. time() . basename($image1_name);
                $image1_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '\\/').'/'.$uploadpath1;
                ////

                if(empty($errors)) {
                move_uploaded_file($image1_temp_name, $uploadpath1);
                $success[] = 'Uploaded!';
                }
            }
            ///
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

                $uploadpath2 = 'upload/';

                $image2_name = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
                $image2_size = $_FILES['image2']['size'];
                $image2_type = $_FILES['image2']['type'];
                $image2_temp_name = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];

                $uploadpath2 = $uploadpath2. time() . basename($image2_name);
                $image2_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '\\/').'/'.$uploadpath2;
                ////

                if(empty($errors)) {
                move_uploaded_file($image2_temp_name, $uploadpath2);
                $success[]= 'Uploaded';
                }
            }

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $table = 'products';

            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `$table` SET `image1` = $uploadpath1, `image2` = $uploadpath2 WHERE `id` = $id");

            }
  ?>
```

All in : image_multi.php
So when i post submit .. the images uploaded successfully but nothing updated in my table

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWM7H.png)

I run this link : mydomainname.com/image_multi.php?id=1

images uploaded but not appears in database at all

Thanks

Comment: I encourage you to use prepared statements to avoid sql injection attacks and not having problems like this one that you forgot to put between single quotes the image1 and image2 values (and also id if it's non numeric)

Comment: can you explain more i'm not professional :)

Answer (score 0):

Check type and length for fields 'image1' and 'image2' in your table

Comment: type is text .. so length not set

Comment: make sure you are passing value of 'id' after submitting your form i.e. once you click on 'Upload', check you are receiving value for 'id'

Answer (score 0):

the problem is definitely in the mysql statement, you didn't quote the filenames that's why the update doesn't run through. in the future simply check the db log for errors.
to fix this should work

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `$table` SET `image1` = '$uploadpath1', `image2` = '$uploadpath2' WHERE `id` = $id");
```

notice the ' enclosing your $vars, that's only for when you need strings in the rows - which you clearly need. I'm not sure the Id should be string, check to see if it's numeric.